# remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); only for certain post types

Tags: filters

I want to try and remove automatic `<p>` tag and `<br>` tag addition for my custom post type.

It looks like

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

will do this, but how would I make the change only for my chosen post type I've tried writing a function for this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function remove_tags() {
    global $post_type;

    if ( 'client' == $post_type ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you putting these functions?

Comment: in my custom post type plugin file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');

//decide when you want to apply the auto paragraph

add_filter('the_content','my_custom_formatting');

function my_custom_formatting($content){
if(get_post_type()=='my_custom_post') //if it does not work, you may want to pass the current post object to get_post_type
    return $content;//no autop
else
 return wpautop($content);
}
```

found this code on stackoverflow - looks to do the trick.

Comment: +1 for finding your own answer :) Please post the URL for the question where you found the code though.

Comment: original can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697465/wordpress-remove-auto-generated-paragraphs-for-speciffic-custom-post-type

Comment: This will break when another plugin wants to do the same for another custom post type.

Answer (score 11):

Hook into `the_content` before the `wpautop` filter has been called, check the post type, and remove the `wpautop` filter, which is added in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` with the default priority `10`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_82860_remove_autop_for_posttype', 0 );

function wpse_82860_remove_autop_for_posttype( $content )
{
    # edit the post type here
    'post' === get_post_type() && remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: After years, I still have problems understanding `priority` handling of filters in WP. Doesn't `0` mean that it's first called and after that the default `wpauto` is called with its `priority` of `10` and puts the `<p>`s back in?

Comment: @VolkerE. `wpautop` is **not** called anymore, because it has been unregistered earlier.

Comment: Oh, for sure. Thanks! And it's not even late at my place right now. :}