# remove and then add wpautop

Tags: wp-autop

I'll start by saying yes, I searched, and *yes*, I found [an answer to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82860/remove-filter-the-content-wpautop-only-for-certain-post-types). It's basically the solution I came up with but I want to make sure this isn't a bad solution.

Here's the real question. I want make the post title a part of the first paragraph on certain types of posts. My solution is straightforward. I call this instead of `the_content` for a certain category.

```
function yb_link_post() {
  $link_post_title = '<b class="headline"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></b>';
  $link_post_content = $link_post_title . ' — ' . get_the_content();

  remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
  echo wpautop($link_post_content);
  add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
}
```

So is this a bad way to do this? I have a hunch that removing and then adding `wpautop` could have repercussions that I'm not considering. Can anyone tell me if this is a good solution, or if there's a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, removing `autop` filter from `the_content` filter tag makes no sense here, because you never apply `the_content` filters in your code...

Let's take a look at the source code of `the_content()` function:

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
        $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
        $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
        echo $content;
}
```

As you can see, it applies `the_content` filter to the result of `get_the_content()` function.

So how your function should look like?

```
function yb_link_post() {
    $link_post_title = '<strong class="headline"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . esc_attr(get_the_title()) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></strong>';
    $link_post_content = $link_post_title . ' — ' . get_the_content();

  // you don't have to remove autop filter if you want to run it anyway... and content is already modified, so it will be `autop`ed correctly.
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $link_post_content);
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    echo $content;
}
```

PS. You shouldn't use `<b>` - use `<strong>` instead. Also you should escape eveything correctly (i.e. if you print `get_the_title()` as html attribute, you should run `esc_attr` on it).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! As for `<b>` vs. `<strong>`, in this particular context, `<b>` will actually be more correct since I'm not applying any semantic meaning or extra importance to it. In fact, the more I think about it, I should probably just remove that element and put the class on the link instead. It's really only there because it started as the `<h1>`, and I changed it to `<b>` when I made it inline.

Comment: Well, in that case adding class to link would be OK.